# How to set attributes in URL to call a servlet in gwt + java?

Tags: java, servlets, gwt, download

I want to open a file stored on server on click of a  button on client side.
On click handler I added code-

```
 String url="../../downloadServlet?fileName="+fileN+"?recodId="+recoId;
 Window.open(url, "", "");
```

In this url , I want to add 2 diffrent parameters- FileName and RecordId.
Above implementation is not working for this. How can i pass more parameters in a request?

Thanks

Comment: maybe you want to use: `String url="../../downloadServlet?fileName="+fileN+"&recodId="+recoId;` ..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use `&` instead of another `?`:

```
String url="../../downloadServlet?fileName="+fileN+"&recodId="+recoId;
```